# Could not load file or assembly when loading WCF library in AppDomain

Tags: wcf, appdomain

I have a WCF service with a service library. I want to create an instance of class library in a new AppDomain but this throws an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1.dll' or one of its dependencies.

```
 //Class library
 public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject
 {    
        public string Method1(int i)
        {
            return "int=" + i;
        }
 }

//Class WCF Service
public class Service1 : IService1
{
     public string GetData(int value)
     {
          string name = typeof(Class1).Assembly.GetName().FullName;
          string type_name = typeof(Class1).FullName;
          var _Dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SubDomain", null, info);

          //why is it not working? 
          //exception - not found assembly file
          var _Factory = _Dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(name, type_name) as Class1;

          //it's worked
          //var _Factory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(name, type_name) as Class1;

          return _Factory.Method1(value);
     }
}

//Client method to service
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Service1Client cc = new Service1Client())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client opened.");
        Console.Write("Enter integer: ");

        int i = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);
        try
        {
            var r = cc.GetData(i);
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        cc.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Client closed. Press Enter key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[Link to solution](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1IeQ2R659MVVjdFbXJadGluckk)

Comment: You should probably address a few issues with your question. First, please don't just link to your solution on another site, but add the relevant snippets of code in the question. Second, tell us what you've tried to resolve the issue, and why it didn't work. Note that you can edit your question at any time.

Comment: It tells you what assembly can't be loaded. Please provide full exception message

Comment: one of your references doesnt exist where you expect it to. if this is the same machine - check you've not referenced one that was in an obj/debug folder somewhere - if this is a seperate machine (build server perhaps) - check you've referenced a local version NOT a gac version. (click the reference and look at the file path under its properties in VS)

Comment: @Chris why is it working?
var _Factory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(name, type_name) as Class1;

Comment: what value does this give you? string name = typeof(Class1).Assembly.GetName().FullName;

Comment: @Chris name="ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". It's name reference library.

Comment: so does the reference exist? where are you referencing it from?

Comment: Yes. He referencing from Project.

Comment: Self hosting solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

//Self hosting solved the problem

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost:7777/Service1");
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), url))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the AppDomains base and relative directories resolved this issue for me at least

```
string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string relativePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
m_domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", null, basePath, relativePath, false);
```